# Verify values of selctbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm new to this. I'm using in a html page with 2 selctboxs, one for min price and the other for max price and a hidden input to put on it the combination of the two values of the selectboxs.

```
<div class="option-bar mini first">
                    <label><?=__("Min Price")?></label>
                    <span class="selectwrap">
                        <select name="min-price" id="pmin" class="search-select">
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option value="1000">$1000</option>
                            <option value="2000">$2000</option>
                            <option value="3000">$3000</option>
                            <option value="4000">$4000</option>
                            <option value="5000">$5000</option>
                            <option value="6000">$6000</option>
                            <option value="7000">$7000</option>
                            <option value="8000">$8000</option>
                            <option value="9000">$9000</option>

                        </select>
                    </span>
                </div>

<div class="option-bar mini">
                    <label><?=__("Max Price")?></label>
                    <span class="selectwrap">
                        <select name="max-price" id="pmax" class="search-select">
                            <option></option>
                            <option value="2000">$2000</option>
                            <option value="3000">$3000</option>
                            <option value="4000">$4000</option>
                            <option value="5000">$5000</option>
                            <option value="6000">$6000</option>
                            <option value="7000">$7000</option>
                            <option value="8000">$8000</option>
                            <option value="9000">$9000</option>
                            <option value="10000">$10,000</option>

                        </select>
                    </span>
                </div>

<input type="hidden" id="prix" name="prix" class="sel2" value=""  />
```

and i got this jquery code :

```
$("#pmin, #pmax").change(function(){
    update();
});

function update() {
    $("#prix").val($('#pmin').val() + "-" + $('#pmax').val());
}
```

So what i want to do is when the user select options in the two selectbox, verify if the min price value is lower than the max price value and if not show a message.

Thnx a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#pmin, #pmax").change(function() {
  if ($("#pmin").val() && $("#pmax").val()) { //check if both have values
    if (parseFloat($("#pmin").val()) > parseFloat($("#pmax").val())) { //check if valid range
      alert('invalid range')
      return;
    }
  }
  update();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".search-select").change(fucntion(){
    var max_val = $("#pmax").val();
    var min_val = $("#pmin").val();
    if(max_val != '' && min_val != '' && max_val < min_val){
        alert("Max value is less than Min value.");
    }
```

});

Try this..!!

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the `change` and `update` method as shown below:

```
$("#pmin, #pmax").change(function() {
    if ($('#pmin').val() != "" && $('#pmax').val() != "") {
      update();
    }
  });

function update() {
  var computedValue = parseInt($('#pmin').val()) - parseInt($('#pmax').val());
  if (computedValue < 0) {
    alert('Invalid selection.');
  }
  $("#prix").val(computedValue);
}
```

Refer the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/Lc2d6brs/).